# Validation of multiple reactjs components

Tags: javascript, validation, reactjs, components

I have multiple component in a form Like this:

```
<Form_element check_empty={true} required={true} rows="1" label="Question"</Form_element>
```

The definition of Form_element is:

```
var Form_element = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
  return({valid:false});
  )},
  render:function()
  {
     return(<input required="" type={this.props.type}/>)
  }
})
```

How can I check if multiple Form_element's are invalid when the form is submitted.(Using refs on each component is a bad idea)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do it with state

```
class FormElement extends Component {
   constructor(props){
     super(props);
   }
   render(){ 
      const { state,value,type } = this.props;
      let errorClass={color:'red'};
      let normalClass={color:'black'};
      return (
         <div>
         {     (state == 0)?
               <input style={errorClass} type={type} 
                      value={this.props.value}>:
               <input style={normalClass} type={type}
                      value={value}>   
         }

         </div>

      );
   }
}
class Parent extends Component {
   constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.onCheck = this.onCheck.bind(this);
     this.state = {name:{value:'',status:0 },address:{ value:'',status:0} };
   }
   onCheck(){

    let ok = {};

    Object.keys(this.state).forEach(x=>{
       let element = this.state[x]; 
        // check if the status is alright
        if ( cond satisfy your validation ){
           ok[x] = this.state[x];
        }

    }); 
     // let's say that the checking was done we update the state to rerender

    this.setState(Object.assign({},this.state,ok);

   }

   render(){

    return (
      <div>
         <FormElement valid={this.state.name.status} type={'text'}></FormElement>
     <FormElement valid={this.state.address.status} type={'text'}></FormElement> 
     <button onPress={this.onClick}>submit</button> 
      </div>
     );
   } 
}
```

just play the value through state at the hosting container of this component, PS: rerender only happens through setState()

Comment: So you are saying that value should be passed on the parent as prop.Still there are multiple components to validate.
`<Form_element/><Form_element/><Form_element/><Form_element/>`
each having different valid state

Comment: u maintain a state on the parent container .. like this.state = {model:[]}; then each time u decide to check just validate that and set the state as valid or not through setState

Comment: Your idea is great.Assigning just a part of status array to false or true and maintaining state in parent is a good idea.Thanx.